How fix this issue: "A conflicting instance of UnrealBuildTool is already running"
While trying to compile the C++ project in UE5.3, I get these errors:
Using bundled DotNet SDK version: 6.0.302
Running UnrealBuildTool: dotnet "..\..\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.dll" -ModuleWithSuffix=Inventory,6303 InventoryEditor Win64 Development -Project="D:/Users/user/Documents/Unreal Projects/Inventory/Inventory.uproject" "D:/Users/user/Documents/Unreal Projects/Inventory/Inventory.uproject"  -IgnoreJunk
A conflicting instance of UnrealBuildTool is already running.

I have no idea what to do with it.

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=conflicting+instance+of+UnrealBuildTool&t=canonical&ia=web -- just throw the error message at a search engine and read what comes up. Have you tried anything yourself to resolve the issue? Please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Point is, your question title "How to fix this issue" would fit just as well on any other question here. Try to be descriptive of what the problem is, like e.g. the error message instead of "this issue"!

From the information you have given, I would say get rid of the conflicting instance and your problem is solved. Info from an Unreal forum:

In Task Manager, kill dotnet.exe
If that fails, restart your computer


I killed .NET in task manager and it worked. Thank you.

".NET Host"*    ...
